# Question about Circulant Matrices and Isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $G$ be the subgroup of all circulant matrices in $GL_3(\mathbb R)$, and let $H$ be the subgroup of matrices in $G$ of the form $
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x & z & y \\
        y & x & z \\
        z & y & x \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

I'd like to show that $G/H\cong \mathbb Z_2$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I know that $G/H=\{AH|A\in G\}$ and that every matrix in $G$ is of the form:

$$
        A= \begin{bmatrix}
        x & z & y \\
        y & x & z \\
        z & y & x \\
        \end{bmatrix} or \begin{bmatrix}
        x & y & z \\
        y & z & x \\
        z & x & y \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$$

So to show that they are isomorphic is it enough to define an isomorphism?:
$f(AH)=\begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $A$ is of the first form} \\
1 & \text{if $A$ is of the second form}
\end{cases}$

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is your definition of "circulant matrix"? With the usual definitions, $H$ would be the set of all invertible circulant matrices and $G$ is the union of all invertible circulant matrices and all invertible anti-circulant matrices. But then $G$ is not a multiplicative group. Do you mean the group generated by the set of all invertible circulant or anti-circulant matrices?

Comment: @user1551 By "circulant matrix" I just mean a Matrix of one of those $2$ forms. $A= \begin{bmatrix}
        x & z & y \\
        y & x & z \\
        z & y & x \\
        \end{bmatrix} or \begin{bmatrix}
        x & y & z \\
        y & z & x \\
        z & x & y \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Why is $G$ not a group with matrix multiplication?

Comment: You are right, they do form a group.

Comment: @user1551 Do you know how I could prove that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.  Of course, you do need to confirm that your mapping is in fact an isomorphism, but this is straightforward.  First establish that the mapping $f$ is a homomorphism.  Then show that the kernel of your homomorphism is $H$.  Since you are dealing with elements of $GL_3(\mathbb R)$, this can be done by direct multiplication of your two different forms.

I should point out that you are using an unconventional definition for a circulant matrix.  Elements of your group $H$ fit the standard definition of a circulant matrix while elements of your group $G$ have a more general form.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused as to how there can be an isomorphism between the two groups. Aren't there an infinite number of elements of those two forms? and by extension an infinite number of elements in the set $\{AH|A\in G\}$? But $\mathbb Z_2$ only has $2$ elements.

And I'm not sure what's up with the non-standard definition. That's just the one used in my book.

Comment: How would I show that $f(AHBH)=f(AH)+f(BH)$? There doesn't seem to be in the definition any value for $f(AHBH)$. Also, wouldn't I need to show that $ker(f)$ is the identity in $H$ (that is, $f$ is one-to-one)?

Comment: For your first comment, there's nothing paradoxical about taking two infinite groups, forming a quotient, and obtaining a finite group.  You're doing the same thing when you take a quotient of $\mathbb Z$ and $2\mathbb Z$ to form $\mathbb Z_2$.  And in fact, the problem you posed is very similar to this example.   I'll sketch out a solution in my next comment.

Comment: For the homomorphism $f:G \to \mathbb Z_2$, simply let $f$ map $g$ to $0$ if $g\in H$ and let $f$ map $g$ to $1$ if $g\in G\backslash H$.  Suppose we have $h_i, h_j\in H$ and $g_i, g_j\in G\backslash H$.  You can use direct multiplication to show that $h_i h_j \in H$ and $g_i g_j \in H$, while $h_i g_i \in G\backslash H$ and $g_i h_i\in G\backslash H$. Using these facts, you can then show that $f$ is a homomorphism (obviously with kernel $H$) as desired.

Comment: Thanks! I'm clear on the Homomorphism part. But I'm confused as to what the kernel being $H$ has to do with this being an isomorphism.

Comment: Ah, perhaps you haven't been introduced to the *first fundamental isomorphism theorem*.  See, for example:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstGroupIsomorphismTheorem.html

Comment: Ah, yes. I recall that theorem now. Thank you.